# Basic perl threading: threads->list() does not decrease

Tags: multithreading, perl

It looks like `thread_sleep` is not ending properly.

I could handle it using thread queues, semaphores and such but I am interested in what the problem may be here.

This code never ends, as the `threads->list()` size never decreases.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Thread;

my @threads;

my $count = 0;

while ( scalar( @threads ) < 10 ) {

    my $thr = threads->create( 'thread_sleep' );
    push @threads, $thr;
    $count++;

    print "Spawned Thread nr. $count\n";

    while ( threads->list() > 4 ) {
        print "too many threads, sleeping a second...\n";
        sleep( 1 );
    }
}

sub thread_sleep {
    sleep( 5 );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threads work a lot like processes -- after a thread exits, it stays around in the thread list as a "zombie" thread until another thread (not necessarily its parent) calls `$thr->join` to collect its return value.

You aren't calling `$thr->join` anywhere, so these threads are piling up. You can use `threads->list(threads::joinable)` to check which threads have exited and are now joinable.

(Alternatively, consider using `Parallel::ForkManager` to manage multiple worker processes. Perl interpreter threads are messy and are best avoided.)

Comment: Well, until the process exits. But yes.

Comment: threads->list(threads::running) was perfect for my usecase, anyway the answer is perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: @duskwuff: You really shouldn't overlook the use of `Thread` instead of `threads`. The module is broken while the pragma is a little less so.

Comment: @Borodin Oh, whoa, I missed the `use Thread` line -- the code appears to only reference `threads` though…

Comment: It does. But it's still inappropriate to use `Thread` at all when it's supposed to be a bridge module for ten-year-old code! See my (non) answer.

Comment: `Parallel::ForkManager` is a great recommendation, but it uses `fork` (or emulated `fork` on non-Linux systems) and not `threads` (which are emulated everywhere!) There is no great solution for Perl 5, and it's one of the things that Perl 6 fixes extraordinarily well.

Answer (score 1):

You are relying on a very outdated Perl module that was introduced in 1998 and removed from core in 2007. You don't say what version of Perl you're running, but software doesn't work like automobiles where a pristine example of very old edition is laudable

You need to update your installation

The [documentation for the `Thread`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.27.1/lib/Thread.pm#DEPRECATED) module says this (markup original)

> **DEPRECATED**
>
> The `Thread` module served as the frontend to the old-style thread model, called *5005threads*, that was introduced in release 5.005. That model was deprecated, and has been removed in version 5.10.
>
> For old code and interim backwards compatibility, the Thread module has been reworked to function as a frontend for the new interpreter threads (*ithreads*) model. However, some previous functionality is not available. Further, the data sharing models between the two thread models are completely different, and anything to do with data sharing has to be thought differently. With *ithreads*, you must explicitly `share()` variables between the threads.
>
> You are strongly encouraged to migrate any existing threaded code to the new model (i.e., use the `threads` and `threads::shared` modules) as soon as possible.

Comment: Oh, i ws not aware of this. I am bound to work with 5.8  (stupid, i know) but it already has threads.